# Four columns in a div: three of the the width depends on content; fourth one takes the rest

Tags: css, responsive-design

Essentially I have one div, that holds four divs which all have float: left apart from the last one it has float: right.

I am building a responsive web page. I would like basically all three columns apart of the column "Name" to take up all the width they need. The remainder of the width should go into that column - if that makes sense.

```
<div style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 10px 0 10px; font-size: 1.2em; overflow: auto;">
            <div style="float: left; width: 5%;"><input type="checkbox" id="ID"></div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 5%;">Code</div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 80%;">Name</div>
            <div style="float: right; width: 10%;">100 &euro;</div>
        </div>
```

Found the solution!

I found the solution! Removing the float and adding overflow hidden on the column that should adjust helped to get what I needed!

```
    <div style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 10px 0 10px; font-size: 1.2em; overflow: auto;">
            <div style="float: left; width: auto; margin-right: 1%;"><input type="checkbox" id="ID"></div>
            <div style="float: left; width: auto; margin-right: 3%;">Code</div>
            <div style="float: right; width: auto; margin-left: 3%;">100 &euro;</div>
            <div style="overflow: hidden;">Name></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/WHwbC/) of the code in your question, for people to play around with

Comment: I think you can get the width of the first three columns correct with `width: max-content`. However, [`max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Values) is “experimental” and currently [only works in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width).

Comment: When you find a complete solution on your own, you should post it as an answer to your own question, not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the float of a div forces content to flow around it, so you should be fine with simply not floating the rightmost div and letting it default. In your case, just remove the styling from the 100 euro div and it'll take up whatever space is left.

The problem here is that setting explicit width percentages isn't exactly what you want - what you need to do is dynamically resize the divs based on their interior content using javascript.